# Using firebase cloud functions to store/access a stripe api key -billing issues

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to store my stripe private key using firebase cloud functions.I set my key using this command: `firebase functions:config:set stripe.secretkey="MY STRIPE KEY"` and this is my code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.testkey);

//looks like deleting the lock file helped get this to work

exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.region('us-east4').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let customerId;

        //Gets the customer who's email id matches the one sent by the client
        const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
            email: req.body.email,
            limit: 1
        });

        //Checks the if the customer exists, if not creates a new customer
        if (customerList.data.length !== 0) {
            customerId = customerList.data[0].id;
        }
        else {
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.body.email
            });
            customerId = customer.data.id;
        }

        //Creates a temporary secret key linked with the customer
        const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
            { customer: customerId },
            { apiVersion: '2022-11-15' }
        );

        //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: parseInt(req.body.amount),
            currency: 'cad',
            customer: customerId,
        })

        res.status(200).send({
            paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
            ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
            customer: customerId,
            success: true,
        })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }
});
```

However today I checked my billing and it seems to have charged me $0.29. Now keep in mind this is still a private project and not been deployed. How can I fix this? Hopefully this won't be daily.

Comment: Hello, what is your exact question? To have your bill reduced to 0$? And what do you mean by "a project not been deployed"?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm trying to avoid getting billed at this point because my project is still in development (i'm still working on it)